# How can I fully kill a program and/or python code running on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, sublime-text-2

I was running Sublime Text 3, but it seems I've created an infinite loop somehow. I was writing an image to file but when I look in the folder I see that the image is flickering between one of those generic image icons and the actual image. So clearly python keeps rewriting the file.

I already tried closing all of the tabs and then closing the text editor, but I still can't delete the file in my folder. Is there maybe a way to fully kill either sublime or the python code running in the background?

Comment: have you not solved this yet?! e.g. "I still can't delete the file in my folder."   If you have then post your answer

Comment: he solved it.. And this question should not have been bumped to the homepage by the system. It's a very very basic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was restart my computer. Woohoo.

Comment: It isn't true "science" way :)

Comment: @Alex I hear ya, but I was frustrated with this for about 30 minutes and I just wanted to move on with my project :/

Comment: If you familiar with console's `cmd`, run it as administrator next time and use `tasklist` to spot process ID aka PID and then use `taskkill /PID 12345 /T` where 12345 is a PID of misbehaved process

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  In two days, you'll be able to accept your own answer to indicate that the problem is solved.

Comment: please accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

Run in powershell

```
 taskkill /F /IM python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a right click on empty space of task bar and choose from menu 'task manager', look over list processes and when you spot "sublime"(or python process), make a right click on it and choose - "kill process tree". 
If you want more details about running processes you might want to use much better program than "task manager", it called "[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)" that can be downloaded from official microsoft site

Comment: I only see this when I right click on it: http://imgur.com/a/qupQ3

Comment: NO, click on "Details" tab

Comment: Found the end process tree, but that didn't work.

Comment: Try "Process explorer", but run it "as administrator"